# Kivy TreeViewButton not defined

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am working on an app and I have to add a screen with my organization chart, I was thinking of using a `TreeView` as it's the natural fit but I need the nodes to be buttons. 
Also, the app already has 2 screens with buttons defined with all the people in my organization. How can I use their ID to populate the `TreeView`? Or is there a better solution?

My *.py*

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.button import Button, ButtonBehavior

class UI(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UI, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Screen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class TreeViewButton(Button, TreeViewNode):
    pass

Builder.load_file("test.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return UI()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

my .kv file

```
#: kivy 1.10.0
#: import TreeViewLabel kivy.uix.treeview.TreeViewLabel


<UI>:
    Screen1:
        name: "screen1"

        BoxLayout:

            TreeView:
                id: tv

            Button:
                size: (200, 50)
                size_hint: (None, None)
                text: "add_node"
                on_press: tv.add_node(TreeViewButton(text = "Node..."))
```

When I press the button I get

```
NameError: name 'TreeViewButton' is not defined error.
```

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the .py is called main.py then you must import it:

**test.kv**

```
#: kivy 1.10.0
#: import TreeViewLabel kivy.uix.treeview.TreeViewLabel
#: import TreeViewButton main.TreeViewButton

<UI>:
    Screen1:
        name: "screen1"

        BoxLayout:

            TreeView:
                id: tv

            Button:
                size: (200, 50)
                size_hint: (None, None)
                text: "add_node"
                on_press: tv.add_node(TreeViewButton(text = "Node..."))
```